# Neo4j 2.0 wildcard search on label names

Tags: regex, wildcard, cypher, neo4j

When dealing with properties in Cypher, you can use regular expressions to match property values like so:

```
Match (n)-[:IS_A]-() where (n:Course_Driving_001) and (n.name =~ '(?i).*criteria.*' or n.description =~ '(?i).*criteria.*')   return distinct n limit 20;
```

I'd like to do the same thing with a label name.  I'd like to get all unique labels that contain a certain string.  Something like:

```
 Match (n)-[:IS_A]-() where (n:Course_*_001) return distinct n;
```

Can this be done is Cypher?  or the RestAPI?  Regular expressions?

I'm using Neo4j 2.0 Release.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You cannot directly use regex on labels. However using the `labels` function this is possible:

```
MATCH (n)-[:IS_A]->() 
WHERE any(l IN labels(n) WHERE l=~'Course_*_001')
RETURN distinct n;
```

Please be aware that this query is potentially expensive as it touches all nodes in your db. You might want to refactor your data model to use multiple labels, e.g. `Course` *and* `Course_xyz_001`. In this case you can use `MATCH (n:Course) ....` which reduces the number of nodes to visit in first place.

Comment: +1 on the multiple labels, alternatively use an index on `:Course(type)` and put "Driving_001" in your `type` attribute. That might be slower though.

Comment: Even with multiple labels, I think this would end up being too slow.  I think I'll try storing the label names in their own graph whenever a new one is made.  That way I'll be able to find them quickly.  I may be able to use your example for other cases though.  Thanks!